# What does opposite angle brackets <> mean?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-methods, vdm++

Example 1

```
forall x,y in set {1,…,5} & X <> y => not m.temps(x) = m.temps(y)
```

Example 2

```
exists i,j in set inds m.temps & i <> j and m.temps(i) > 400 and m.temps(j) > 400
```

What does <> in those sentences mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means "not equal to". So "x <> y" is the same as "not x = y".

Comment: Thanks! I just recently found it out myself by reading the vdm manual. :D